# Delete possible despite Foreign Key

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm facing a behavior that I don't technically understand.

Let's assume I have a data model that looks like the following.

```
class MastoList(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mastolist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    list_id = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    base_url = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    max_id = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, default='0')
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

class Toot(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    list_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('mastolist.id'), nullable=False)
    account = db.Column(db.String(255))
    account_displayname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    uri = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
```

The generated DB structure looks like the following.

```
CREATE TABLE mastolist (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    list_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    base_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    max_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE toot (
    id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    list_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    account VARCHAR(255), 
    account_displayname VARCHAR(255), 
    created_at DATETIME, 
    uri VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    content TEXT, 
    reblogged BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(list_id) REFERENCES mastolist (id), 
    UNIQUE (uri)
)
```

The database storing the data contains one row for `MastoList` with `id` = 1. `Toot` contains several rows all having set `list_id` = 1. If I try to delete the row from `MastoList` using DB Browser for SQLite I get the expected `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` error.

Trying to delete the row using the following code works without any error.

```
session = Session(db)
masto_list = session.execute(select(MastoList).filter(MastoList.id == id)).scalar_one()
session.delete(masto_list)
session.commit()
```

Afterwards all rows in `Toot` still have `list_id` to 1.

Only if I add

```
toots = db.Relationship('Toot', backref='MastoList')
```

to the model of `MastoList` I also get the expected foreign key error when trying to delete the row with my code.

Can anybody explain why it's possible to delete the row using my code meaning the DB constraint is simply ignored?

Comment: SQLite disables automatic enforcement of foreign key constraints by default. Use `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` to enable them, then you'll get an error when deleting the parent row. See https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Thanks @barmar. Maybe add it as answer so that I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For backwards compatibility, SQLite doesn't enable foreign key enforcement by default. You can use

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

to enable it. Then you should get an error if SQLAlchemy doesn't enforce the FK itself (which the `backref` option enables).